# Replace a column in another table in mysql with a condition

Tags: mysql

I want to replace tags rows in my database news table product where the product name is equal to the product name in another table product.

I want to copy the tags column from the products database to the product database tags must be in the correct row like the name column must match both tables.

I tried a query but it send me an error:

```
Table to copy = product
Table from copy products
Condition (name=name) or (slug=slug)
```

In both Table:

```
UPDATE product
   set tags = (
       select tags
       FROM products
       where product.name = products.name
   );
```

It gives an error:

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

It works with:

```
UPDATE product
   set tags = (
       select tags
       FROM products
       where product.id = products.id 
   );
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: [UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) -> "Multiple-table syntax"

Answer (score 0):

What I have found to better understand and make sure you ultimately want in the final update, yet also make sure you are getting the records intended.  Write the select first.

```
select
      np.name,
      np.tags NowTags,
      op.tags OtherTags
   from
      NowProduct np
         JOIN OtherProduct op
            on np.Name = op.Name
```

Once you have this confirmed, just change the SELECT to an UPDATE.  You can use the "alias" for the table being updated.  I found its best to make sure your query is correct to see what records WILL be queried and what the before and what you WANT updated values should be.  Once good, then apply update.

```
update np set
      tags = op.tags
   from
      NowProduct np
         JOIN OtherProduct op
            on np.Name = op.Name
```