# MYSQL ERROR CODE: 1288 - can't update with join statement

Tags: mysql, join

Thanks for past help.

While doing an update using a join, I am getting the '**Error Code: 1288. The target table _____ of the UPDATE is not updatable**' and figure out why.  I can update the table with a simple update statement (UPDATE sales.customerABC Set contractID = 'x';) but can't using a join like this:

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT *                        #where '*' contains columns a.uniqueID and a.contractID
    FROM sales.customerABC
    WHERE contractID IS NULL
    ) as a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT uniqueID, contractID
    FROM sales.tblCustomers
    WHERE contractID IS NOT NULL
    ) as b
ON a.uniqueID = b.uniqueID
SET a.contractID = b.contractID;
```

If changing that update statement a SELECT such as:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM opwSales.dealerFilesCTS
    WHERE pcrsContractID IS NULL
    ) as a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT uniqueID, pcrsContractID
    FROM opwSales.dealerFileLoad
    WHERE pcrsContractID IS NOT NULL
    ) as b
ON a."Unique ID" = b.uniqueID;
```

the result table would contain these columns:

```
a.uniqueID, a.contractID, b.uniqueID, b.contractID
59682204,   NULL,       NULL,       NULL
a3e8e81d,   NULL,       NULL,       NULL
cfd1dbf9,   NULL,       NULL,       NULL
5ece009c,   ,           5ece009c,   B123
5ece0d04,   ,           5ece0d04,   B456
5ece7ab0,   ,           5ece7ab0,   B789
cfd21d2a,   NULL,       NULL,       NULL
cfd22701,   NULL,       NULL,       NULL
cfd23032,   NULL,       NULL,       NULL
```

I pretty much have all database privileges and can't find restrictions with the table reference data.  Can't find much information online concerning the error code, either.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Mayby my solution / explanation on another item might help get what you need.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74913771/replace-a-column-in-another-table-in-mysql-with-a-condition/74914361#74914361

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update a sub-select because it's not a "real" table - MySQL cannot easily determine how the sub-select assignment maps back to the originating table.

Try:

```
UPDATE customerABC
JOIN tblCustomers USING (uniqueID)
SET customerABC.contractID = tblCustomers.contractID
WHERE customerABC.contractID IS NULL AND tblCustomers.contractID IS NOT NULL
```

Notes:

- you can use a full JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN, since you *want* uniqueID to exist and not be null in both tables. A `LEFT JOIN` would generate extra NULL rows from tblCustomers, only to have them shot down by the clause requirement that tblCustomers.contractID be *not* NULL. Since they allow more stringent restrictions on indexes, JOINs tend to be more efficient than LEFT JOINs.
- since the field has the same name in both tables you can replace `ON (a.field1 = b.field1)` with the `USING (field1)` shortcut.
- you obviously strongly want a *covering index* with (uniqueID, customerID) on both tables to maximize efficiency
- this is so **not** going to work unless you have "real" tables for the update. The "tblCustomers" may be a view or a subselect, but customerABC may *not*. You might need a more complicated JOIN to pull out a complex WHERE which might be otherwise hidden inside a subselect, *if* the original 'SELECT * FROM customerABC' was indeed a more complex query than a straight SELECT. What this boils down to is, MySQL needs a strong unique key to know *what* it needs to update, and it must be in a *single* table. To reliably update more than one table I think you need two UPDATEs inside a properly write-locked transaction.

Comment: Thanks, LSerni, for a complete answer.  I get all 4 bullets, but the 1st and 4th really help me understand what I am doing wrong.  Needing a 'real' table to update is what I needed and how to use the WHERE to isolate what I need.  Thanks.